# Stanford corenlp pause and continue annotation pipeline

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Typically when you use the corenlp annotation pipeline for say NER you would write the following code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
pipeline.annotate(document);
```

I would like to perform sentence splitting i.e. `ssplit` in the above pipeline.  But then I would like to remove sentences that are too long before I continue the rest of the pipeline.  What I have been doing is performing sentence splitting, filtering the sentences by length, then performing NER by applying the entire pipeline i.e. `tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner`.  So essentially I have performed `tokenize` and `ssplit` twice.  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  For example performing `tokenize` and `ssplit` then pausing the pipeline to remove sentences that are too long, then resume the pipeline with `pos`, `lemma`, and `ner`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two pipeline objects, with the second one taking the later annotators. So:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
pipeline.annotate(document);
```

Followed by:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "pos, lemma, ner");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props, false);
pipeline.annotate(document);
```

Note, of course, that some of the annotations (e.g., character offsets) will be unintuitive if you delete intermediate sentences.

Comment: Can you explain what the ```document``` variable is in each of the two pipelines.  If they are both strings then wouldn't the second pipeline require tokenization as well.  You cannot do pos tagging without tokenization, right?

Comment: Ok now I see that ```pipeline.annotate(document)``` mutates the document.  Now I need a way to mutate ```document``` between the two pipelines to filter sentences by length.

Comment: That's correct. `document` is an `Annotation` object that gets mutated in place by the pipeline.